# In a spring boot project, how to load application.yaml into Java Properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, yaml

If I have the following properties in application.yaml:

```
myPro:
   prop1: prop1value
   prop2: prop2value
....
```

Is there a way to load this into a Java `Properties` object?

Answer (score 12):

By default, Spring already puts all those application properties in its environment which is a wrapper of [`Properties`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/Environment.html), for example:

```java
@Autowired
private Environment environment;

public void stuff() {
    environment.getProperty("myPro.prop1");
    environment.getProperty("myPro.prop2");
}
```

---

However, if you just want to use the values, you can always use the `@Value` annotation, for example:

```java
@Value("${myPro.prop1}")
private String prop1;
@Value("${myPro.prop2}")
private String prop2;
```

---

Lastly, if you really want a `Properties` object with just everything in `myPro`, you can create the following bean:

```java
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "myPro")
@Bean
public Properties myProperties() {
    return new Properties();
}
```

Now you can autowire the properties and use them:

```java
@Autowired
@Qualifier("myProperties")
private Properties myProperties;

public void stuff() {
    myProperties.getProperty("prop1");
    myProperties.getProperty("prop2");
}
```

In this case, you don't necessarily have to bind it to `Properties`, but you could use a custom POJO as well as long as it has a fieldname `prop1` and another fieldname `prop2`.

These three options are also listed in [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html):

> Property values can be injected directly into your beans using the `@Value` annotation, accessed via Spring’s `Environment` abstraction or bound to structured objects via `@ConfigurationProperties`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem using the dependency on my `pom.xml`

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```